# CORS Error --Why XMLHttpRequest get's made at 'webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-select/dist/index-75b02bac.browser.esm.js' instead of server

Tags: reactjs, webpack

My implementing my own library and using that in my application through npm link. But getting error while using component.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-select/dist/index-75b02bac.browser.esm.js' from origin 'http://localhost:2000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

My webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  devtool: "eval-source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
        // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
        // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
        oneOf: [
          {
            test: /\.(tsx|ts|mjs)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: "babel-loader",
              options: {
                plugins: [
                  ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"],
                  ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", { regenerator: true }],
                ],
                presets: [
                  "@babel/preset-env",
                  "@babel/preset-react",
                  "@babel/preset-typescript",
                ],
              },
            },
          },
          // Currently react-styleguidist uses a dependency called acorn. Acorn has recently switched to offering a .mjs
          // distributable, and react-styleguidist seems to be using it. However, they did not add support to their internal
          // webpack config to account for this. Therefore, I have modified our webpack config to account for it. Hopefully,
          // this is fixed in a later version and we can remove this loader and the .mjs extension from our resolve:extensions
          // list below. Here is a link to the GitHub issue referring to what I'm describing: https://github.com/styleguidist/react-styleguidist/issues/1300
          {
            test: /\.mjs$/,
            use: {
              loader: "babel-loader",
              options: {
                presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
              },
            },
          },
          {
            test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
            use: [
              { loader: "style-loader" },
              { loader: "css-loader" },
              { loader: "sass-loader" },
            ],
          },
          // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
          // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
          // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
          {
            exclude: [/\.js$/, /\.ts$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
            loader: require.resolve("url-loader"),
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".mjs", ".js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".json"],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
    publicPath: "",
    filename: "bundle.js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs",
  },
};
```

Comment: So, you created a library which is a React component? And, you are getting this error when using (at import) that component in another React project? Is that library's webpack config you have shown in question?

Comment: Yes..you are right.